# how to test the jest custom environment

Tags: jestjs

i would like to test the jest custom environment class with different testEnvironmentOptions.

here is the class:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

and here is the test:

```
it('some Test', function() {
  const instance = new CustomEnvironment({
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
      providers: []
    }
  });
});
```

which throws the following exception:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'projectConfig' of 'config' as it is undefined.

```
  14 |
  15 |   constructor(config, context) {
> 16 |     super(config, context);
```

any thoughts how to initiate the custom environment class correctly?

Answer (score 0):

seems like there were some [changes on version 28](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/43b91ff0a977858f781a9c36e6e717433588a24e/website/versioned_docs/version-28.x/UpgradingToJest28.md).

> The constructor of test environment class now receives an object with
> Jest's globalConfig and projectConfig as its first argument. The
> second argument is now mandatory.

changed the test to be in the right object structure:

```
it('some Test', function() {
  const instance = new CustomEnvironment({
    configProject: {
      testEnvironmentOptions: {
        providers: []
      }
    }
  });
});
```